# Saving Multiple Bitmaps into a file in Android

Tags: android, caching, bitmap

Is it possible to save and retrieve an array of Bitmaps in a single file using android and java? Saving a single bitmap can be achieved as follows

```
File cacheFile = getCacheFile(cacheKey);
out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(cacheFile));
boolean didCompress = data.compress(compressFormat, quality, out);
```

Now since getCacheFile(cacheKey) will return only a single file, I have only one file to which I can add the bitmaps how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on why you need to store multiple files/what you're trying to do the easiest thing to do would probably create a wrapper class for this purpose. Instead of putting the Bitmap into the cache you could read the bitmap(s) already in, append the new bitmap data to that an cache the whole thing. Your wrapper class would need to know (either through serialization or parsing the actual file data) where each bitmap file is stored and from there you can store/retrieve them individually. I don't think there's a standard API to do what you're requesting.